# SSH tunnel not working with sql developer

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I am trying use SQL Developer with SSH tunnel. I configured the ssh tunnel and the sql developer connection, but when i test the ssh tunnel i receive below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TcpipForwarder is closed
    at org.apache.sshd.common.forward.DefaultForwardingFilter.startLocalPortForwarding(DefaultForwardingFilter.java:196)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.AbstractClientSession.startLocalPortForwarding(AbstractClientSession.java:333)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ssh.core.Tunnel.connect(Tunnel.java:91)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ssh.core.HostConnection.openTunnel(HostConnection.java:89)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ssh.core.Client.openTunnel(Client.java:333)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ssh.navigator.SshController$4.doWork(SshController.java:252)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ssh.navigator.SshController$4.doWork(SshController.java:248)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Using putty with ssh tunnel is not working. :(

How can I solve it?

Thank you,
Stefan